# Is it normal to take days to compile PostgreSQL from source code?

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 10 beta from source code by following their documentation. Is it normal that make and make install take more than 12 hours to complete? Would using extra CPU cores and memory speed things up? Is there a binary available for Debian 8?

Thank you!

Comment: No! I have done it on a 7 year old laptop with 2GB of RAM and it takes between 1 and 2 hours to run make. ./configure and install (I always split the steps) take approx 1 - 1.5 mins! You don't have a permissions issue or free space issue? Check your df -h and your OS stats during the compile (open another console tab).

Comment: When you compiled did you use **make -j 7** where 7 is the number of concurrent compiles?

Comment: no I did not do concurrent -j 7

Comment: @geeko there is your problem. Set -j = <total cores> and try again.

Comment: @EvanCarroll No, unless it's some wackly highly parallel 486, that won't help them. One core should be just fine to build postgres in a few hours on a REALLY slow system. It takes minutes on my laptop.

Comment: @geeko There's something seriously wrong there. Is it taking ages to compile each object file? What's it spending time on - look at `top` ? There's no way it should take hours even if your Debian 8 system is on some ten-year-old CPU. I'm wondering if you're on a cloud/virtual host of some kind and the underlying host system is overloaded or defective.

Comment: I am building it on a VMware installation of Debian 8 with 2 CPU cores and 4 GB RAM... it keeps showing "Checking file.xyz" messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How long it takes to compile will depend on a big number of factors, mostly the hardware (or resources of your virtual machine) on which you're compiling, plus your OS and environment settings, plus what else is your computer doing while you compile.

To have a *reference* of times, you can check [PostgreSQL BuildFarm](https://buildfarm.postgresql.org/).

For instance, for a certain system called *gull*, which runs *Debian 8.3*, the [gull PostgreSQL BuildFarm for date 2017-07-06](https://buildfarm.postgresql.org/cgi-bin/show_log.pl?nm=gull&dt=2017-07-06%2003%3A20%3A18) shows a **Total run time
01:05:48**.

Your system *might* actually be an order of magnitude slower and take 12 hours. It seems a bit "overkill", but possible. Although I don't know the specifics of compiling PostgreSQL for Debian (specially, how parallel it can be made), I'm sure that more memory and more (and faster) cores will decrease compilation time. It is also very likely that, at this phase of development, some settings to ease debugging might be different from releases on *production*, and (maybe) take longer to compile.

As for packages already compiled, check

- [Search PostgreSQL at debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=postgresql)
- Package [postgresql-10 (10~beta1-1)](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/postgresql-10)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I install the binaries in the links that you thankfully provided?

Comment: I can't get into details, because I've never installed on Debian. Check https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_want_to_try_the_beta_version_of_the_next_PostgreSQL_release.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a binary available for Debian 8?

Yes, and you should be using the binary. For Debian 8 (Jessie) you'll find

- [PostgreSQL 9.4](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&searchon=names&keywords=postgresql)
- In [jessie-backports, you can find 9.6](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie-backports&searchon=names&keywords=postgresql)

Just use `apt-get` to install the version you need,

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

When it comes to compilation the biggest thing is the `-j` flag which compiles in parallel. As @cybernard suggested in the comments.

If you want to compile PostgreSQL and not all of the dependencies, you can use apt-get to install the source that Debian compiles their versions with

```
apt-get source postgresql-9.4
```

Comment: i am looking for pg 10 beta

Comment: @geeko then use the official repository https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/

Comment: To be a bit more precise, in order to test the upcoming version on Debian, you could go to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_want_to_try_the_beta_version_of_the_next_PostgreSQL_release